# Concatenate checkbox.text when checked

Tags: c#, concatenation

I have 6 checkboxes. When they are checked I want to concatenate the checkboxes.text. For example, if all checkboxes are checked, I need this code:

```
if (cbCough.Checked == true && cbFever.Checked == true && cbHeadache.Checked == true && cbLoss.Checked == true && cbMyalgia.Checked == true && cbSore.Checked == true)
 {
 str += cbFever.Text + cbCough.Text + cbHeadache.Text + cbLoss.Text + cbMyalgia.Text + cbSore.Text;
 }
```

But there are also other cases, like only the first checkbox is checked, the first and the second are checked, and so on.

This way is too long and does not cover all possible outcomes.

Comment: WinForms or WebForms? Are they in the same container, and are there no other checkboxes in the container? Then find all checkbox controls, and if they're checked, append their text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your checkboxes into a list and then you can use LINQ:

```
List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new List<CheckBox>
{
cbCough, cbFever, cbHeadache, cbLoss, cbMyalgia, cbSore
};
string str = string.Join("", checkBoxes.Where(cb => cb.Checked).Select(cb => cb.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to defined collection of checkboxes and loop over them:

```
ComboBox[] cbxArr = new [] { cbCough, cbFever, cbHeadache, cbLoss, cbMyalgia, cbSore};
string str = string.Empty;
foreach(var cb in cbxArr)
{
    if(cb.Checked)
        str += cb.Text;
}
```

Only thing you need to make sure of is correct order of checboxes, if it matters.

Comment: @JianCeleste Please, accept the answer that has helped you.